# Does the server PHP memory limit apply to SQLite acces

Tags: php, memory, pdo, sqlite

My web host one.com has a preset PHP memory limit of 128 MB, and they say it cannot be upgraded. I use a PHP script to collect data and store it in a SQLite db on the server (NB file db, not memory) .

When the database reaches 128mb, it stops the php script running. I have had to clear the database back to scratch to get it going again. At first I dismissed it as a glitch but then it happened at 128mb again (lesson to be learned about dismissing things you can't explain..!).

I can't work out why a memory limit is affected by the SQLite db file size. The script accesses the SQLite db through the PDO abstraction layer. I could change it to use the SQLite3 specific database extension, but that'd be without verifying what the issue was first. And as such there's no way to know if it would help.

Before I delve deeper, is anyone aware of what could cause such an odd situation, am I completely missing something obvious?

Comment: SQLite itself is not part of PHP, so it isn't subject to PHP's memory constraints (even if you do use an "in memory" database)

Comment: Yes I understand they are totally separate, but thanks for clarifying the matter of in memory databases. I guess the reason I am asking is because of an answer from one.com Support, who connected my query about SQLite db with a PHP memory limit of 128mb

Comment: Your script would hit memory limit before sqlite database reaches 128mb, remember, your script uses memory too.

Comment: @Marek - I'm accessing the data through PDO statements, just searching for records to see if a match exists, and inserting single records if they don't. There are 3 tables with max 8 cols. These are small transactions. The memory would be freed after each php call

Comment: @topspeed I mean: if size of sqlite database would be counted into memory limit as Jake suggests, you wouldn't get to 128mb, your own code, variables etc takes memory too. I'm surprised what Mark Baker claims, that in memory database is not part of memory constraints.

Comment: @Marek - OK understood, I hadn't connected your comment with Jakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though one.com classifies SQLite as PHP memory. This is more a problem for their customer support than SO.

The obvious solution would be to move to a host with a less absurd limit.

Comment: I have just put that point to them, asking why are they suggesting a connection between PHP limit and SQLite files size.

Comment: Seems that is the case, one.com have confirmed